# using JS to recursively call an xml web service

Tags: javascript, web-services

I have question of both logic and implementation for which so far googling netted me nothing of use.

- I need to access a webservice that can provide me 1,000 results at a
  time queries can return roughly 21,000 results
- I have no control over the webservice, just need to use it
- JS runs on a local machine or another webserver (ie NOT the server with the data)

So I wrote a small js script that calls it and parses the data, now my problem is that I written it using synchronous call (ie async: false). This presents a bunch of issues some of which mean that it only seems to work on chrome and not other browsers.

---

**So my questions are:**

How do you handle logic of making an asynchrnous call and parsing the results? - by the time I come out of the call, I have no results and they come in a bit later. How can I use them properly?

How can I do so using a webservice which I will need to poke a few times, for instance if I got a total of 10,000 results and the service returns only 1,000 at a time.

I am rather confused about these two aspects of the problem and would appreciate any help. I have tried to use ajax and cors, they both work to varying degree, but I do not understand how to handle the second part (only getting a subset of results at a time).

What methods are there for this given that originally I could not use async: true due to the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". And I cannot modify the webservice.

---

Parsing a processing is already handled which I parse each individual xml reply to extract data I need and process it all at the later stage.

Would appreciate pseudo code for a reply, I am only starting out with learning JS so do not know all it is capable of doing.

Comment: As it stands, this is too broad. Try to limit yourself to one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [promises](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/ajax-deferreds):

```
// calls your web service asynchronously   
function request(page) {    
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/xml-service/',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            delay: 1,
            json: JSON.stringify(ret)
        }
    });
}

// retrieve all results recursively
function requestItems(page, items) {
    return request(page).then(function(data){
        if (data.currentPage > data.totalPage) {
            return items;
        } else {
            return requestItems(data.currentPage + 1, items.concat(data.items));
        }
    });
}

function requestAll(){
    return requestItems(1, []);
}

requestAll().done(function(items) {
    console.dir(items);
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for that, that actually did it only in the end I used a GET since it also retrieves the data but does not complain about the "access control allow origin"!